# Java library for matrix operations involving complex numbers?

Tags: java, math, matrix, complex-numbers

I want to rewrite some signal processing code of mine from C++ to Java.  I wind up with matrices of complex numbers (numbers with imaginary components).  I need to find the inverse of an NxN complex matrix, as well as the principle eigenvector.

There are several Java libraries to do this with real numbers, but I couldn't find anything that supported complex numbers.  I found one library but it was proprietary and had to be licensed.

Has this been implemented anywhere?

I can always wrap the needed C code with JNI, but I was doing this to avoid platform dependence.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/linear.html).  I believe that it carries on from where JAMA left off.

Comment: Ah, they do support complex numbers.  Its a little hidden in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry for barging in, but if you have, could you point where in the documentation you found anything on complex eigenvectors ?

Comment: Barging in?  The party was over six years ago.  Maybe you should dig into it and report back.

Answer (score 3):

In a past university course, I worked with [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a java LAPACK that's basically an automatic translation of the FORTRAN one: http://www.netlib.org/java/f2j/ . The packaged sources don't include the complex ones unfortunately, but you can apply the same technique to those, I guess. Might be a lot of effort though, and I can't vouch for the performance to be satisfactory.

Also have a look at JavaNumerics at http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/#libraries . They have a quite comprehensive list of things that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Michael Thomas Flanagan's Java Scientific Library: http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/index.html

I found it much easier to use than the others mentioned in this post so far.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  Unfortunately, like the other libraries posted, it cannot compute the eigenvectors of a complex matrix.

Answer (score 0):

[cern.colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/index.html) is worth trying.